# Use '&' to create pointer to member error upgrading VS 2013 to 2019

Tags: c++, class, pointers

This code compiles file in VS 2013 but in VS 2019 I get this error almost anywhere I try to use Callee function's

```
typedef void (XMessage::*FUNCTION)();
void    FgAddTimer(FUNCTION function, DWORD dwTime);
```

```
CursorMsg.FgAddTimer((XMessage::FUNCTION) XCursorMsg::OnTimer, 200);
```

gives

```
'XCursorMsg::OnTimer': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

or

```
class XCallee
{
public:
    
    virtual ~XCallee() {}

    typedef void (XCallee::*FUNCTION)();

    virtual char *GetType();
};

class CStaticModel : public CBaseModel
{
public:
    BOOL    Load(LPCSTR szName, DWORD dwFlags, XCallee *pCallee, XCallee::FUNCTION pFunction, DWORD dwPriority=0);
    BOOL    Load(LPCSTR szName, DWORD dwFlags = 0)  { return Load(szName, dwFlags, this, (XCallee::FUNCTION) OnLoad);}
    void    OnLoad();
}
```

I have OnLoad declared like this

```
void CStaticModel::OnLoad()
{
}
```

gives

```
'CStaticModel::OnLoad': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

How would I go about solving this mitigation issue?

Adding `&` causes more errors

```
error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

Comment: Add the `&`? `&XCursorMsg::OnTimer`.

Comment: What's the function signature of `FgAddTimer`?

Comment: Have you actually tried doing what the error message tells you to do, using "'&' to create a pointer to member"?

Comment: I tried adding `&` I get new error `error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`

Comment: Ahh `&CStaticModel::OnLoad` seems to work good, I tried just `&OnLoad`

Comment: See also [Error C3867: non-standard syntax; use ‘&’ to create a pointer to member: What it means and how to fix it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201007-00/?p=104341).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Don't do 
`&OnLoad`

but instead do
`&CStaticModel::OnLoad`